# Did the Simpsons (cartoon) couple ever cheat on each other?

Tags: character, the-simpsons

Homer and Marge look like a loving couple. Has any one of them committed adultery and cheated before?

Comment: https://fansided.com/2015/09/27/homer-cheat-on-marge-the-simpsons/

Comment: @user7294900 The article indicates that that episode was a dream, or something, in which case it doesn't count.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, the closest that Homer ever came to cheating on Marge was in [The Last Temptation of Homer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Temptation_of_Homer). The closest that Marge ever comes to cheating on Homer would probably be in [Mommie Beerest](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Mommie_Beerest) or [Life on the Fast Lane](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Life_on_the_Fast_Lane).
Disclaimer: I think I've missed the last few seasons.

Answer (score 6):

Homer and Flanders both committed bigamy in the season 10 episode [Viva Ned Flanders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viva_Ned_Flanders) when they each drunkenly married cocktail waitresses.

Whether the marriages were consummated is unknown, but bigamy itself *is* cheating.